# How do I return Manager name instead of ManagerID in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql, relationships

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT Name, ManagerID FROM User
```

The result yields a User's name and their corresponding Manager's user ID.

How can I return the Manager's name instead of the ID in SOQL?

Comment: is your `ManagerID` field is a custom field of the `User` object itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A great way to learn SOQL is to use the Schema Browser in the Force.com Eclipse IDE. In the screen shots below, I browsed to the User object:

[image]

Then scrolled down to the ManagerId field (note it is of type reference), then clicked on Type Data > Reference To > User > Fullname

[image]

And, SFDC has automatically built the SOQL for you in the Query pane:

[image]

Note: The 'u' can be omitted from your SOQL

Comment: Very handy! I guess that SF uses "references" rather than JOINs. I am more used to the SQL syntax and didn't know how such relationships would translate to SF without a JOIN.

Comment: Apparently when you run this query the entire Manager user object is returned, not just the name. I would have thought that the dot syntax would remedy this, but it didn't. I tried to run the code in both the IDE and Developer console with the same difficulty. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this:

`SELECT Name, ManagerID, Manager.Name FROM User`

Manager is lookup to User